Characterizing all total derivatives of a homogeneous differential polynomial
A total derivative here means a differential polynomial (D.P.) $P(u,u_1,u_2,...,u_n)$ (Note: $u=u(x),u_k=\partial_x^ku(x)$) such that there exists another D.P. $G$ such that $P=\partial G$.
The question here is to characterize all such D.P.s with given finite degree (w.r.t. $[u,u_1,...,u_n]$).  For example, all D.P. with degree 1 is the vector space spanned by $\{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\}$.
Another example, when $n=1$, all degree 2 D.Ps are given by $\{uu_1\}$ since $uu_1\sim \partial u^2$, $\sim$ here means they are equal up to a multiplier constant and total derivatives.

The space of polynomials in $u,u_1,\ldots,u_n$ of given degree $k$ is a finite dimensional, real vector space $V_k$ spanned by monomials $u^{\alpha} := u_0^{\alpha_0} \ldots u_n^{\alpha_n}$ with $\sum \alpha_i = k$. Let's call $V_k^o \subset V_k$ the subspace spanned by monomials with no $u_n$, and $V_k^p$ spanned by monomials with $u_n$. The question is to describe the image of $\partial : V_k^o \oplus V_{k+1}^p \to V_k$. Since the involved spaces are finite dimensional and we have a standard basis of monomials, we can write down the matrix and try some calculations.

On a second a thought, It is unclear to me how the differential acts on the degree of polynomials containing $u_n$. This part has to be properly revised in the above reformulation.
